# Using arbitrary methods or attributes as fields on Django ModelAdmin objects?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Using Django 1.1:

The [Django admin docs describe](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) using arbitrary methods or attributes on a ModelAdmin object in the `list_display` class attribute. This is a great mechanism for displaying arbitrary information in the list display for a Model. However, there does not appear to be a similar mechanism for the change form page itself. **What is the simplest way to accomplish this useful little feature to display arbitrary, non-field-derived information on the ModelAdmin change form page?**

A concrete example of the desired setup:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def registration_key(self, obj):
        """Special method for looking up and returning the user's registration key
        """
        return 'the_key'

    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 
                    'registration_key')  # <- this works

    fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_staff',
              'registration_key')  # <- this DOESN'T work?
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add the method to the 'readonly_fields' tuple as well.

Comment: I wish! `readonly_fields` is new in Django 1.2, and I'm stuck with 1.1 for now.

Comment: You're out of luck then, I'm afraid - there's no way to do this in 1.1 without severe hacking.

Comment: Worked for me in django 3.2.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
class CustomUserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    registration_key = forms.IntegerField()                                 

    class Meta: 
        model = User   

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def registration_key(self, obj):
        """Special method for looking up and returning the user's registration key
        """
        return 'the_key'

    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 
                    'registration_key')  # <- this works

    fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_staff',
              'registration_key')
```

Comment: Interesting. Thankfully, I've been able to throw off my chains of 1.1 since asking this question, but you've confirmed this works in 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before by overriding the template for the change form, and accessing custom methods on the model. Using `fields` is asking the admin to try to add a form field for your method.

Comment: Admin templates fill me with fear and trembling, but I might have to consider this.